# sqlalchemy mysql segmentation fault on connect

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I have a piece of code that used to work fine until very recently:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(
      'mysql+mysqldb://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(
          user,
          password,
          hostname,
          database),
      echo=False,
      pool_recycle=300) # re-connect after 5 minutes

connection = engine.connect()
```

Now, it fails immediately with a segmentation fault. Has the syntax changed?

The server runs MySQL 5.7.19 and is definitely responding. My installation is sqlalchemy-1.2.4 and mysql-python-1.2.5. I'm using python 2.7.14.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a workaround using `pymysql` instead of `mysqldb`:

```
engine = create_engine(
      'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(
          user,
          password,
          hostname,
          database),
      echo=False,
      pool_recycle=300)
```